# Why doesn't the compiler generate compile errors if an incorrect argument type is passed to a struct initialiser list?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

I have defined a struct, which has a constructor:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct(const int value)
        : value(value)
    {
    }
    int value;
};
```

and the following objects:

```
int main()
{
    MyStruct a (true);
    MyStruct b {true};
}
```

But I haven't received any compile errors, either with MVS2015 or Xcode 7.3.1.

1. Why am I not getting any compile errors?
2. How do I make the compiler help me detect this? (Initially, the struct was written to have `bool` data, but after some time, code changed and `bool` became `int` and several bugs were introduced.)

Comment: I'm surprised that the second one is allowed, but I get the same (no errors).

Comment: There is a value-preserving integral promotion from `bool` to `int` which is applied implicitly. The brace initialization is only ill-formed for *narrowing* conversions.

Comment: :( yes me too, as I hope compiler will help me.

Comment: Well, `true` and `false` can be automatically casted to an `int`.

Comment: Some information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/175926/1460794).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: "automatic casting" isn't a thing. A cast is an explicit operation.

Comment: How to make a code which is preventing from this kind of situation?

Comment: @TM: You can use a constructor template and then apply some type traits.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, I've seen your comment. _Integral promotion_ is of course the correct term. I just didn't know better how to say that.

Comment: In C++ language both `int` and `bool` are *integer types* (aka *integral types*). So, in a way, a conversion from `bool` to `int` is not that different from, say, a conversion from `short` to `int`. There's nothing "incorrect" about that argument from the language point of view.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

A `bool` can be implicitly converted to an `int` in a way that's value preserving. The only disallowed conversions with brace initialization are [*narrowing* conversions](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7) (e.g. the reverse `bool{42}`).

If you want to ensure that your class is constructible **only** with `int`, then the direct way is simply to `delete` all the other constructors:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    explicit MyStruct(int i) : value(i) { }

    template <typename T>
    MyStruct(T t) = delete;

    int value;
};
```

Here, `MyStruct{true}` and `MyStruct(false)` will yield calls to `MyStruct::MyStruct<bool>`, which is defined as deleted and hence is ill-formed.

The advantage of this over `static_assert` is that all the type traits will actually yield the correct values. For instance, `std::is_constructible<MyStruct, bool>` is `std::false_type`.

Comment: Yeah, that's better.

Comment: Very nice, good point that `is_constructible` doesn't consider deleted overloads.

Comment: "narrowing" is a misnomer... it implies that one is narrower than the other, however `int->double` and `double->int` are both considered "narrowing".  Maybe "lossy" would be a better description

Comment: @M.M It's what the standard [calls it](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7) for better or for worse, so I'll use it for consistency.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a construction that allows you to only initialize your class from an `int` value:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct MyStruct
{
    template <typename T>
    MyStruct(T t) : value(t)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "Bad!");
    }

    int value;
};
```

That's because the template argument deduction required by this constructor template will produce the exact type of the argument and not perform conversions, so you can perform tests on that type.

You should perhaps also or instead use SFINAE to constrain the constructor, so that `MyStruct` doesn't present itself as constructible from anything.

Furthermore, you should probably also make the constructor template `explicit` so that random integers don't become `MyStruct` instances.

In other words, I'd write it like so:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    template <typename T,
              typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, int>::value>>
    MyStruct(T t) : value(t) {}

    // ...
```

Comment: It should be `"Good!"` now.

Comment: I know the question is tagged as C++11 but I think it's worth noting that `static_assert` does not exist in previous versions.

Comment: @Michael: That's true. The SFINAE version can be used in C++98, too (as long as you write the trait(s) yourself).

Answer (score 8):

The simplest solution is to declare a bool constructor as deleted isn't it?

```
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct(bool) = delete;

    MyStruct(const int value)
    : value(value)
    {
    }
    int value;
};
```

example error output:

```
...
/Users/xxxxxxx/play/fast_return/skeleton/main.cpp:68:14: error: call to deleted constructor of 'MyStruct'
    MyStruct b {true};
             ^ ~~~~~~
/Users/xxxxxxx/play/fast_return/skeleton/main.cpp:57:9: note: 'MyStruct' has been explicitly marked deleted here
        MyStruct(bool) = delete;
        ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Yeah but now you have to do that for all the other things that convert to `int`, too.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit true, but I'm struggling to see that as a problem. The compiler will catch narrowing conversions if the OP uses brace-initialisation as per his example. And if he needs specific constructors for each type of int then he's going to have to write (or template) specific constructors anyway.

Comment: Will brace-initialisation catch `short`->`int` conversion? That's already one more constructor you need to manually `delete`. And how do you know your users will use brace-initialisation? Didn't get your last sentence; OP wants _one_ working constructor.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit no, short->int isn't narrowing, but neither can I see it being (semantically) a problem to allow the conversion. It's a natural conversion, compatible with all other uses of short ints. Preventing instantiation from a bool (sort of) makes sense, because a bool is subtly different in meaning to an int in terms of human reasoning.

Comment: Okay well I don't think I disagree with you, but that's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit (pendantry alert) I didn't answer his question 1 as I think it's covered by the other answers well enough. Question 2 merely asks for help in finding 'this' problem, which was a design decision to convert from bool to int as the data type. While I agree that the question is open to interpretation, I think with respect, that I have answered Q2, as far as I understand his predicament and meaning to be. I.e. he wants to catch all places where a bool is used at the call site.

Comment: Oh yeah you've certainly done that. I was only critiquing the solution as it compares to the others :)

Comment: My interpretation here but I believe this perfectly answers the OP question, specially considering "*Initially struct was written to have bool data*".

Answer (score 7):

Because a `bool` can be *implicitly converted* to an `int`.

This is a language feature that you cannot turn off, sorry.

Comment: I tried and `explicit` doesn't prevent this. Don't we need `explicit` on the built-in int? :)

Comment: @flatmouse: Haha damn

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So no way to catch this kind of staff during compile time?

Comment: @TM: Kerrek already showed what is basically your only possibility. It's a little heavy-handed for me, fundamentally altering what your constructor is and how it works. But that may be fine for you. Otherwise, no, no way.

Comment: I have seen worse things, namely `false` being promoted to a `QString`. I guess because `false` is 0, which is `NULL`, which is a `const char *`, and there is a constructor `QString(const char *)`.

Comment: @Giorgio: `NULL` is not a `const char*` but I take your point

Comment: That was my explanation fot why the compiler did not complain about a function with return type `QString` returning `false`. Doesn't `NULL` convert to any pointer type?

Comment: @Giorgio: "converts to" is not the same as "is", is what I'm saying

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: As far as I know only one implicit conversion is performed (but I may be wrong). In this case, from `const char *` to `QString` via the constructor `QStrring(const char *)`.. So it must be that `false` is considered a `const char *`. I'll have to look up the exactrules that are applied, because I am not sure.

Comment: @Giorgio: It may just be a language issue but to say that "`false` is considered a `const char *`" is absolutely wrong.

Comment: @Giorgio `false` is definitely not considered a `const char*`. But `QString(false )` probably invokes `QString(QChar)` which invokes `QChar(int)`.

Comment: @Barry: Invoking QString(QChar(int)) would involve two conversions. As far as I know, at most one implicit conversion is allowed.

Comment: I have created a question to try and clarify what is happening in my example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214420/conversion-of-false-to-object-via-const-char-constructor

Comment: @Giorgio Yeah, one standard conversion and one user-defined conversion. That's perfectly fine. You just can't have more than one of either.

Answer (score 0):

the value true is converted to value 1 (int).