# How to prevent implicit value-preserving conversion of a templated alias?

Tags: c++, templates

I'd like to add compile-time checking for different meanings of `double`. In the real world, I'm trying to make sure all calculations are done in consistent units. For the purposes of this question, I've concocted a toy example in which numbers have flavors.

I've been trying to achieve this based on a template parameter. Using the c++0x aliases feature described in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2795024/2789327), I declared a `Number<Flavor>` as:

```
enum Flavor { Cherry, Plum, Raspberry };

template <Flavor> using Number = double;
```

This gives me the ability to declare local variables or parameters as particular flavors of Number, then use those variables as ordinary doubles in most contexts.

My problem is, I can't find a way to declare a function that will only accept a particular flavor as its argument:

```
void printCherryNumber(Number<Cherry> num) { cout << num << endl; }

int main() {
    Number<Cherry> a(5);
    Number<Plum> b(6);
    Number<Raspberry> c(3.1415);

    printCherryNumber(a);
    printCherryNumber(b);  // O, if only this could be a compiler error.

    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to make `printCherryNumber(b)` fail to compile because `b` is a `Number<Plum>` not `Number<Cherry>`. Many existing questions tackle variations on this problem with solutions that seem to not work on the type alias construct I've used for `Number`.

## Stuff I've Tried

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37191980/2789327), I see the suggestion to add a templated version of the function that explicitly does nothing or breaks, as in

```
template <typename T> void printCherryNumber(T num) = delete;
```

This has no effect at all, and why should it? `Number<Plum>` is really `double` and `Number<Cherry>` is also `double` so the compiler never bothers with the templated version.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37191814/2789327) suggests using a single templated function and static asserts, as in:

```
template <Flavor F> void printPlumNumber(Number<F> num) {
    static_assert(F == Plum, "Wrong number flavor!");
    cout << num << endl;
}
```

This fails because regardless of the actual value of `F`, `Number<F>` is still just `double` and so I get an error about not being able to infer the value of `F`.

Elsewhere someone [suggests explicit specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/176181/2789327), which also fails for this case:

```
template <Flavor F> void printRaspberryNumber(Number<F> num) = delete;

template <> void printRaspberryNumber<Raspberry>(Number<Raspberry> num) {
    cout << num << endl;
}
```

Here, the compiler treats the call as ambiguous, in part again because it can't infer a value for `F`.

## Elephant in the Room

I could, of course, make `Number` a single-value struct in the form of

```
template <Flavor> struct Number { double value; };
```

but I'm trying to avoid this option because I'm not terribly thrilled about the idea of having `.value` all over everywhere in my code, nor am I especially eager to define operators for `Number` that just proxy down to double.

## Obligatory ideone

http://ideone.com/4HiYtI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this approach:

```
enum Flavor { Cherry, Plum, Raspberry };

template <Flavor> using Number = double;
```

is that alias templates are transparent. `Number<Cherry>`, `Number<Plum>`, and `double` are all the same type. That doesn't solve your problem at all.

---

What you want is typically called an *opaque typedef*. You really do want your last option:

```
template <Flavor>
struct Number {
    double value;

    operator double() const { return value; } // for convenience
    Number& operator=(double ); // if necessary
    // possibly more operations
};
```

This way, `Number<Cherry>` and `Number<Plum>` are *different types*. They are *not* convertible to each other. And `double` is not implicitly convertible to either.

---

You can also take a look at [`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html) and its implementation, it's intended to solve this problem too.

Answer (score 1):

The option you're trying to avoid is really the only way to do this.

A template alias is what it is: an alias. A template alias is equivalent to the underlying type. In all respects.

```
template <Flavor> using Number = double;
```

This means that `Number<Flavor>` is a `double`. It is not anything else. `Number<Plum>` is a `double`, too. This is pretty much the same as doing a global search/replace of either one of them to `double`. The end result will be identical. The type is exactly the same.

You can only "declare a function that will only accept" a specific type. Except using a template alias, the template alias ***is*** the same type, as such it is not possible to declare a function that accept a `double`, but does not accept a `double`. It is a logical falsity.

Wrapping a `double` in a `struct` is the only way to achieve strict type checking, of this kind. It's not that bad. Toss in a few overloads, a few `operator`s, and your wrapped `struct` will enforce strict type checking, and the compiler is likely to produce identical code, with no runtime penalty.